# VMPinterest Not working for Ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, pinterest

i want to integrate Pinterest to my app for both ipad and iphone version. for that i do some googling and find [VMPinterest](http://www.varshylmobile.com/pinterest-framework-for-ios#comment-4) framework. i download its demo its working fine with iphone but not working with ipad version.

Following issue i find it

**its not authenticate properly it showing signing is successfully every times although i pass wrong email or pass.**

**its not able to get the board name**

plz help me out if any body used this framework for ipad or if you have another way to integrate  Pinterest than plz answer or comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to download this API from this link: https://github.com/Lascorbe/LASharekit

Its working fine for me. Merge this into your App.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the latest version of VMPinterest framework (they have released a new version) and it does works perfectly with iPad (i have tested for ipad mini).

I would recommend  VMPinterest framework. as unlike  others it doesnt take you to web page but it directly get you post the image remotely.

They have also released a demo app using this framework - is live on appstore..
App link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vmpinterest/id607998053?ls=1&mt=8

So the framework is appstore approved.

Its compatible with iOS 4.3 and above and runs on iPod touch/iPhone/iPhone5/iPad/iPad mini

For complete list of features visit [Varshyl Mobile](http://www.varshylmobile.com/pinterest-framework-for-ios/) site